# It's Pi Day - Can we find other Hwang-type identities for $\frac{\pi}{4}$?

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry, pi

(*It was Pi Day, at least in some parts of the world*.)

Hwang's remarkable identities are [Machin-like formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Machin-LikeFormulas.html) (correcting two typos in Mathworld's eqns 33 and 34). The $3$-term,
$$\frac{\pi}4=(n+2)\arctan\frac12-n\arctan\frac13-(n+1)\arctan\frac17\tag1$$
and the $8$-term,
$$\frac{\pi}4=a\arctan\frac12-b\arctan\frac13+c\arctan\frac15+d\arctan\frac17-e\arctan\frac1{239}\\ -f_1\arctan\frac18-f_2\arctan\frac1{18}+f_3\arctan\frac1{57}\tag2$$
where,
$$\small\begin{aligned}
f_1&=3 a - 2 b + c + d + e-5\\
f_2&=a - b + c - 2 e-2\\
f_3&=2 a - b + c + d - e-3
\end{aligned}$$

> **Q:** Are there other parametric Hwang-type identities with at least one free parameter?

**P.S.** It should ***not*** be derived by using the identity: $\cot^{-1}x = 2\cot^{-1}(2x)-\cot^{-1}(4x^3+3x)$.